# How to add drawer functionality in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I stuck on implementing drawer functionality for List view in my screen like inbox view of Gmail application in Android provides . I had tried SwipeListView peoject from 47deg.com but it is not giving me desired results.

As there are new API available who can work for my requirements does any one have any idea how to impelemnt drawer functionality for Android devices 2.1 onwards.

Please see [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9Ri5t_rKr_CUDhtOWVkd28wVEE/edit?usp=sharing) which shows gmail functionality.

Comment: Drawer feature? In Gmail? Could you provide an illustration? That should clear it up (_for me at least_).

Comment: Drawer funtionality means that on any listItem when ever user does fling event say left to right, a new view(backview) will overlap old view(frontview) and if user do the reverse fling event on new view(backview) old view(frontView) will be displayed.

Comment: Well, then calling it a _drawer_ is what confused me. Anyway, the _SwipeListView_ library is the closest that I am aware of that will give you that feature _out-of-the-box_. Besides, if the result that you are, I suppose, unhappy with could be in part because you will need to customize it yourself.

Comment: "I had tried SwipeListView peoject from 47deg.com but it is not giving me desired results" -- please feel free to actually explain what you mean, as nobody will be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: I am having checkbox in backview and i want to capture checked/uncheked event and want to perform some operation based on selection but i am not able to do get the functionality as touch event is consumed by API and it is not passing event to listener. While i am trying to get desired functionality by tweaking the code i am just trying if someone knows any other approach for Drawer functionality.